# How can I improve this Python code to be more efficient?

Tags: python-2.7, sum, max, average, min

I've just started to learn Python (my first dabble in coding) and this is my first time posting... I hope I'm not abusing the forum by asking this question (I'm essentially asking an expert to help me learn). Please let me know if this is frowned upon in the community.

For this assignment from a Michigan open course, I've been instructed to ask a user for input until the user enters "done", at which point the code should calculate the largest, smallest, sum, and average. In all my test-runs, it's worked fine. But I feel like there's probably a much simpler way to write this code. Can anyone offer suggestions for improvement?

```
largest = None
smallest = None
count = 0
sum = 0
while True:
    try:
        num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done" : break
        num = float(num)
        count = count + 1
        sum = sum + num
        avg = sum/count
        if largest is None:
            largest = num
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
        if num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num
        continue
    except: print 'Invalid input'

print "Maximum is", int(largest)
print "Minimum is", int(smallest)
print "Count:", int(count)
print "Sum:", int(sum)
print "Average:", avg
```

Comment: Why do you use `float` and later convert back to `int`?

Comment: I wanted to average to be float, but everything else to be int. If I didn't specify int or float, then a non-numeric value would have worked in the 'try' clause. But if I started with int then I wasn't able to get float(average). Does this make sense? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few things here:

- you can drop the `continue` statement since it is the end of the loop anyway;
- you can compress the `if` statements into `if largest is None or num > largest:` this will *shortcircuit* and make the loop smaller;
- you can use `x += y` instead of `x = x + y`; and
- you do not have to calculate the average *inside* the loop; calculating it once when the loop finishes, is enough.

So:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
count = 0
sum = 0
while True:
    try:
        num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done" : break
        num = float(num)
        count += 1
        sum += num
        if largest is None or num > largest:
            largest = num
        if smallest is None or num < smallest:
            smallest = num
    except: print 'Invalid input'

print "Maximum is", int(largest)
print "Minimum is", int(smallest)
print "Count:", int(count)
print "Sum:", int(sum)
print "Average:", sum/count
```

But in terms of *big oh*, you cannot improve much: calculating the sum, etc. simply require *O(n)* and it also costs *O(n)* to read the input anyway.

Furthermore some software engineering advice: **don't use the blanket exception**, always specify the exception you expect so:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
count = 0
sum = 0
while True:
    try:
        num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done" : break
        num = float(num)
        count += 1
        sum += num
        if largest is None or num > largest:
            largest = num
        if smallest is None or num < smallest:
            smallest = num
    except ValueError: print 'Invalid input'

print "Maximum is", int(largest)
print "Minimum is", int(smallest)
print "Count:", int(count)
print "Sum:", int(sum)
print "Average:", sum/count
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is all very helpful! Is it recommended to specify the exception mostly to make the code more clear (for debugging and what-not)? Or is there another benefit?

Comment: @LaurenGainsbrook: well in this case it does not matter much. But say for instance you also going to open files in the loop, etc. Now say opening a file crashes: do you want to show *Invalid input?* probably not, you want to show a dedicated message, or let the program terminate. In case you define functions, you always should only handle the exception you think you *can* handle on that level, the reminder should be passed to the levels above (in the call stack) and should be handled at that place.

Comment: Ok ok, so depending on what I'm doing in the loop, the error (except function) will be different. I want to identify what error I'm expecting, and respond appropriate. So, then, I could also have two excepts? 
Try..... 
except value error:... except some-other-error:...

Comment: @LaurenGainsbrook: yes or simply one except and let the caller of the function solve the other error. Furthermore in most (complex) code you do not fully know what errors you might get: you call a function, but what the function does is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to accomplish this is to store all of the inputs in a list, and then use the built-ins `min()`,`max()`,`len()` and `sum()` to find values:

```
num=raw_input("Enter a number: ")
nums=[]
while num!="done":       #check if user has finished entering inputs
    try:
        nums.append(int(num))       #append the input as an integer to a list
        num=raw_input("Enter a number: ")   #get another input
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input"

print "Maximum is",max(nums)
print "Minimum is",min(nums)
print "Count:",len(nums)
print "Sum: ",sum(nums)
print "Average: ",sum(nums)/len(nums)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: done
Maximum is 6
Minimum is 1
Count: 6
Sum:  21
Average:  3.5
```

Comment: Only problem with that I think is that in case you would enter billions of number, you will run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into lists a little more. @WillemVanOnsem Is memory only a concern if using a list? So if I were expecting billions of numbers, I wouldn't use a list?